# Microsoft Android application is not matching the signature hash with the application reply URI

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

**Goal:** Use the MS Identity application that was created by [Microsoft](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-android-java/) and try to tailor the application according to our needs.

**Issue** The android application is not matching the signature hash with the Applications' Reply URI.

#### Configuration Values

```
Signature Hash: ga0RGNYHvNM5d0SLGQfpQWAPGJ8=
Redirect URI: msauth://com.azuresamples.msalandroidapp/ga0RGNYHvNM5d0SLGQfpQWAPGJ8%3D
Android:host: com.azuresamples.msalandroidapp
Android Scheme: msauth
```

#### Logs and Screenshots

Logs show: The redirect URI in the configuration file doesn't match with the one generated with package name and signature hash.
[Screenshot of the error in the Android Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyGnm.png)

#### Methods Tried

1. Tried to fix this by changing the android:path value to `/ga0RGNYHvNM5d0SLGQfpQWAPGJ8%3D` however got this message from the UI:
   [Screenshot of the update android:path value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yK4NC.png)
2. Tried to change the Reply URI directly from Azure Portal, but was not able to
3. Tried changing the Redirect URI in the android code to `msauth://com.azuresamples.msalandroidapp/ga0RGNYHvNM5d0SLGQfpQWAPGJ8%3D` but that gave the same error
4. The default library in the code was 1.2, changed it to 1.5+ in gradle and still it didnt work.

#### Configuration Files

auth_config_single_account.json

```
  "client_id" : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "authorization_user_agent" : "DEFAULT",
  "redirect_uri" : "msauth://com.azuresamples.msalandroidapp/ga0RGNYHvNM5d0SLGQfpQWAPGJ8%3D",
  "account_mode" : "SINGLE",
  "broker_redirect_uri_registered": true,
  "authorities" : [
    {
      "type": "AAD",
      "authority_url": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    }
  ]
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.azuresamples.msalandroidapp">
    ...
            <intent-filter>
                ... 
                <data
                    android:host="com.azuresamples.msalandroidapp"
                    android:path="/ga0RGNYHvNM5d0SLGQfpQWAPGJ8="
                    android:scheme="msauth" />
            </intent-filter>
       ...

</manifest>
```

Build-Gradle:app

```
...
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$rootProject.ext.appCompatVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$rootProject.ext.materialVersion"
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

    if (findProject(':msal') != null) {
        // For developer team only.
        localImplementation project(':msal')
        externalImplementation 'com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:1.5.+'
    }
    else {
        // Downloads and Builds MSAL from maven central.
        implementation 'com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:1.5.+'
    }

}
```

### Update

Was trying to avoid this but I have updated my keystore using the debug.keystore that microsoft provides and it works, however this is not solution for production environments. What are the steps I need to take for this to work in the production environment.

Comment: What kind of signature did you use, development or production?
Do you have a proper Android app platform enabled within Azure app -> Authentication tab?

Comment: Yes the Android app platform is enabled with azure app. Also the signature I used is production didnt use default keystore, wanted to generated my own for best practices. I just tried using using development mode using debug.keystoreand it worked? any reason for this, what are the step I need to take to have my own keystore instead of using a default keystore?

Comment: I think that for the Microsoft audit/proof reasons you have to use the default one. That's the only way described in docs.

Comment: We need to generate our own certificate for signing in and connection purposes. So would there be a way to do for production instead? Could not find any documentation on that.

Comment: Hi @HKS,I am revalidating your issue. Meantime can you please go through similar [question in github](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues/914) and conform if it can resolve your issue.

Comment: @HariKrishna--MSFTIdentity the solution that was posted is generating the same signed hashed value regardless of the package. Any ideas on this

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if it will be a relevant answer, but will share my experience.
At some point I run into the same issue, dig into the library and figured out how hash is calculated there. It was something like this (I have translated it into kotlin):

```
try {
        val info = packageManager.getPackageInfo(
            packageName,
            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES
        )
        for (signature in info.signatures) {
            val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA")
            md.update(signature.toByteArray())
            val hash = Base64.encodeToString(
                md.digest(),
                Base64.DEFAULT
            )
            Log.d("KeyHash", "KeyHash:$hash")
        }
    } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
        Log.d("KeyHash", e.toString())
    } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
    }
```

The value calculated this way didn't match the value from running this command:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

But it was the one that msal library expects to get. Same happened on release signature. I haven't yet investigated the reason (maybe I did something wrong), but for now I'm using signature hash got from the first method, and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with cmd and keytool but not get success. Please Try this code to generate key hash programmatically in you code.

```
String packageName = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md;
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            sha1Singature = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
            //String something = new String(Base64.encodeBytes(md.digest()));
            Log.e(AppConstants.TAG, sha1Singature);
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e1) {
        Log.e("name not found", e1.toString());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("exception", e.toString());
    }
```

and then you set this Signature hash to Azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

This is Dome from the MSAL Android team.

If you want to use your own keystore, you will have to [register your own application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app).

com.azuresamples.msalandroidapp was only registered with the signature hash of the provided debug.keystore.

Please let me know if you have any other question. You can also [leave a question in our GitHub repository](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues/new/choose) as well (we're constantly monitoring that one).

Comment: I already registered a new application using a new packagename [com.azure.mycompany] and everything. Generated my own keystore and then ran the keytools command and faced the same issue.

Comment: Have you changed the package name of the app? MSAL validates the registered Redirect URI against the app's package name and signature hash at runtime.